# Java - if a value selected in combox1 then it should be disable in all other combo boxes

Tags: java, swing, combobox, jcombobox

Hello I'm still newbie on java hope to learn this nice feature...
Hello i have 4 combo box that have the same inside and inside of it is

```
-Select-
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
```

and when I choose `Item 1` on `comboBox1`,
 the `comboBox2,comboBox3 and comboBox4` have elements only these

```
-Select-
Item 2
Item 3
Item 4
```

and then when I choose `Item 3` on `comboBox2`, the `comboBox3 and comboBox4` have this leftover elements

```
-Select-
Item 2
Item 4
```

anyone have idea how to do this on Java? I am using GUI Builder on Netbeans...

**EDIT 1**

this is my Code

```
private void jComboBox1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
    jComboBox2.removeItem(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
    jComboBox3.removeItem(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
    jComboBox4.removeItem(jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
}
```

and I add on the same code `jComboBox2, jComboBox3 and jComboBox4` after that...
when I go choose `-Select-` the `-Select-` is gone too... and

one more problem is when I already choose all and thinking to rechange it again... all items are gone and no more choices anymore.. I just want to back the available items again...

**EDIT 2**

**Example**

```
jComboBox1
-Select-
Item 1
Item 2 <-- I select Item2, then the other combo box will remove Item 2**
Item 3
Item 4

jComboBox2
-Select-
Item 1
Item 3 <-- then I select Item 3
Item 4

jComboBox3
-Select-
Item 1
Item 4 <-- then Item 4

jComboBox4
-Select-
Item 1
```

but i'm changing my mind... then I need to go back to  `jComboBox2` to select `Item3`
so I choose
`jComboBox2` and select `-Select-`, so I can select `item3` on `jComboBox4`

but the result is
jComboBox4
null (no items)

Comment: Post your attempts please.

Comment: hello I add the edit...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: what?? i dont understand it?

Comment: please which part of SSCCE isn't ... what

Comment: there are two ways, use a few XxxComboBoxModels then selection only to switch between model or dynamically remove(add too) Items from another JComboBoxes

Comment: can you do a sample code of that add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure which of your two answers will be deleted, but here's the same answer again. Note that you can create all of your JComboBoxes and options using loops to prevent really lengthy repetitive code. Then you can use the getSource() method to tell which combobox the event came from. If you created your JComboBoxes as an array you can loop through them very cleanly. In order to add things back in I would just keep track of what has been selected and in which combobox using a String array. You can then check this array and use it to add items back in as needed. Note that they won't go back in the same order. If you want that functionality you can play around with insertItemAt, but that would probably get a little messy (since the indices are constantly changing since you're adding and removing items) so I've left it out.

```
//Declare and initialize the options that the comboboxes will have
String[] options = {"-Select-", "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"};
//Declare and initialize an array that will hold the currently selected options in each combobox by index
//For example the currently selected value of comboBoxes[1] is selected[1]
String[] selected = {"-Select-", "-Select-", "-Select-", "-Select-"};

//Declare and initialize an array of comboBoxes. 
//Four comboboxes will be created all containing the options array
JComboBox[] comboBoxes = new JComboBox[4];
for(int i = 0; i < comboBox.length; i++) {
    comboBoxes[i] = new JComboBox(options);
}

private void jComboBox1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {
    //Loop through all of the comboboxes in comboBoxes
    for(int i = 0; i < comboBoxes.length; i++) {
        //Check to see if the current combobox in the array matches the source of your event
        if(evt.getSource() == comboBoxes[i]) {
            //Get the string value of the combobox that fired the event
            String currentSelection = (String)comboBoxes[i].getSelectedItem();
            //Make sure that the value actually changed
            if(!currentSelection.equals(selected[i]) {
                //If the previous value of the combobox was "-Select-" don't add it to all the other comboboxes
                if(!selected[i].equals(options[0])) {
                    //Add back the previous value to all comboboxes other than the one that fired the event
                    for(int j = 0; j < comboBoxes.length; j++) {
                        if(j != i) {
                            comboBoxes[j].addItem(selected[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                //If current value of the combobox is "-Select-" don't remove it from all other comboboxes
                if(!currentSelection.equals(options[0]) {
                    //Remove the current value from all comboboxes other than the one that fired the event
                    for(int j = 0; j < comboBoxes.length; j++) {
                        if(j != i) {
                            comboBoxes[j].removeItem(comboBoxes[i].getSelectedItem());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Set the selected item for the combobox that fired the event to the current value
            selected[i] = currentSelection;
        }
    }
}
```